# How do I display HTML tags on the main page of my Wordpress site?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My Wordpress configuration is displaying my content completely stripped off HTML tags on the main page. How do I display HTML tags in my content in this case?

On the post page it's:

```
<code><!doctype html></code>some text....
```

But on the main page it's:

```
<!doctype html>some text.... //For some reasons the tags are removed, why?
```

This is important because I'm applying styles to the `<code>` tag and I don't want code look like normal text on the main page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question is slightly more readable now.

Answer (score 2):

try to wrap it in `<code><pre>code here</pre></code>`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for code highlighters??

Then try out anyone of following plugins:

1. [**SyntaxHighlighter
   Evolved**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/)
2. [**WP-Syntax**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/)
3. [**FV Code
   Highlighter**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fv-code-highlighter/)
4. [**CodeColorer**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codecolorer/)